# RSA Ruby & Android padding issue

Tags: java, android, ruby, encryption, rsa

## The padding problem

1) I'm encrypting a message in ruby using a public key with PKCS1_PADDING.

2) Then converting the output (which is ASCII-8BIT encoded) to hex and sending it to the android devie.

3) On android converting the hex to byte array & decrypting it using private key, I am getting a lot of additional chars. (ON android side its defaulted to RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding).

Example:

Expected string: hello how are you doing ?

Actual string: V')f�rBA�;\�:�D��.a�~�A@�.P�(�  �l��-�ך��\�0}�nj.F�@Ƨ�Wr[��k��Ez��o��偣�*r�����K����1D�涮���U!�t�.UI?�gA��|X��o@v�K��Ə���*�'��n�F������
P܆�0��9m9*u�٘S�1�������<>�L�?��;3�_���~�-)�$�����Ũ
*"���%/Oѡ�k@��hello how are you doing?

### JAVA CODE:

```
public String Decrypt (String result,String privKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromString(privKey);
    Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    String decrypted="";
    try {
        byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(result);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(bytes);
         decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decrypted;

}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len/2];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=2){
        data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }

    return data;
}
```

### RUBY CODE:

```
 require 'openssl'
 require 'base64'

 public_key = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn6fT8ScFrW2FR5bxTeFzsD77nN1W+gL5XUB1yQVNL699y6WISopbQ6lls76XvKfyhJHn7ca8i5rDRXrNnaY1BVvX9n/jKWLw13AQcVG4SjMewMQbW1KXOWFe2cltGxB7dX+4xlnxRtXz26xtOpEoBdMN2LBB39WdMghaLIrzcNu9uj363KK8szs9x9rO9E5BNfaqePFwajJoOXjkc5PUwRHeW2DodQnKfxJhaBwotoBbD6zrx+XPqpEzXD7XLjq2i/MGEuw6XGLCGQ+/zaytiYCDe8gboQ5WkWQtfa0FALve9zguqjpoNouWaK4SBq1kyeFKsdsbmZLC8NdJlSruUQIDAQAB"

 rsa_public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(Base64.decode64(public_key))

 encrypted_string = rsa_public_key.public_encrypt('hello how are you doing ?', OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_PADDING)

 encrypted_string.unpack("H*")
```

Comment: What happens when you do `Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding");`? Never use defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum portability you should use `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` as initialization string for the cipher.

This string has actually been defined in the [Java Standard Algorithm Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#impl) as required for any Java implementation. Of course Android isn't officially Java yet, but you can be sure that Google will try and make sure that it will be Java as close as it gets. So this should be compatible with any Java(-ish) implementation.

What is **not** required by Sun is that the mode of operation (`"ECB"` in above string) and padding scheme (`"PKCS1Padding"`) are the default for `"RSA"`. That why you have to specify those explicitly. Never rely on provider-specific defaults - except when specifying the random number generator.

What you currently get is the `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"` scheme which leaves all the padding intact. So when you look at the plaintext size in bytes it will be identical to the size in bytes of the modulus. And the contents will be the PKCS#1-padding, which is (mostly) randomized for each encryption. Random bytes cannot be converted to text easily, so what you get back mainly looks like garbage.

---

Notes:

- `"ECB"` is a bit of a misnomer by Sun, it should have been `"None"` as only one block of plaintext can be encrypted (in general);
- you should also make explicit the character set when converting bytes to string, even though Android has UTF-8 as default (Java on Windows uses Windows-1252 encoding!);
- the best random number generation is generally pretty platform specific, so using a specific algorithm may actually lower the security of your implementation, doubly so for the ill-defined `"SHA1PRNG"`.